# Unable to install "gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms" plugin to Gatsby blog

Tags: windows, npm, gatsby, netlify

I am unable to install the `Gatsby plugin for Netlify CMS` to my blog. I've been following a tutorial of [adding Netlify CMS to existing blog](https://dev.to/thatgalnatalie/how-to-use-netlify-as-your-cms-for-your-gatsby-blog-6jm) and also referred to this [doc](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms/).

#### Steps to reproduce

Here's a link to my repo:
https://github.com/mohammedasker/blogger

1. Clone my repo and head to the project directory
2. run `npm install --save netlify-cms-app gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms`

#### Expected result

`Gatsby plugin for Netlify CMS` installed successfully.

#### Actual result

Error in installing Gatsby plugin for Netlify CMS.

Here's the error log I got from the terminal:

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! path C:\Users\User\Desktop\Mohd Projects\blogger\node_modules\@emotion\weak-memoize\dist
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Mohd Projects\blogger\node_modules\@emotion\weak-memoize\dist'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Mohd Projects\blogger\node_modules\@emotion\weak-memoize\dist'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Mohd Projects\blogger\node_modules\@emotion\weak-memoize\dist'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!     path: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Mohd Projects\\blogger\\node_modules\\@emotion\\weak-memoize\\dist'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Mohd Projects\\blogger\\node_modules\\@emotion\\weak-memoize\\dist'",
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Mohd Projects\\blogger\\node_modules\\@emotion\\weak-memoize\\dist',
npm ERR!   parent: 'blogger'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

#### Environment

```
 System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.18363
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.13.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    Yarn: 1.21.1 - ~\scoop\apps\yarn\current\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
    npm: 6.12.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  Browsers:
    Edge: 44.18362.449.0
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^2.23.18 => 2.24.11
    gatsby-image: ^2.4.12 => 2.4.13
    gatsby-plugin-emotion: ^4.3.9 => 4.3.10
    gatsby-plugin-manifest: ^2.4.17 => 2.4.21
    gatsby-plugin-netlify: ^2.3.10 => 2.3.11
    gatsby-plugin-offline: ^3.2.16 => 3.2.21
    gatsby-plugin-react-helmet: ^3.3.9 => 3.3.10
    gatsby-plugin-sharp: ^2.6.17 => 2.6.22
    gatsby-remark-prismjs: ^3.5.9 => 3.5.10
    gatsby-remark-reading-time: ^1.1.0 => 1.1.0
    gatsby-source-filesystem: ^2.3.18 => 2.3.23
    gatsby-transformer-remark: ^2.8.23 => 2.8.27
    gatsby-transformer-sharp: ^2.5.10 => 2.5.11
  npmGlobalPackages:
    gatsby-cli: 2.12.60
```

#### Things I tried

I tried installing the plugin in other Gatsby projects as well as running the command again as root/Administrator (Command Prompt). Unfortunately, none of them has worked.

Comment: Did you try installing it without a `gatsby develop` running?

Comment: @FerranBuireu It worked! Installing the plugin without running `gatsby develop` fixed the issue. How did you figure out so fast? Is there an article or links to documentation that explains the problem I faced?

Comment: I've added an answer. I just read the error (and a bit of experience, it happened to me several times).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error show:

> The operation was rejected by your operating system. It's possible
> that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),

Retry the same operation without running a `gatsby develop`.

The errors occur because when running a `gatsby develop` you are reading your `node_modules` folder since a lot of functionalities use it (as imports, live reload, etc). While a program is reading those files, the system is not able to overwrite or install/add new folders from other sources (`npm` in this case) because your operating system is using them.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the `Gatsby plugin for Netlify CMS` plugin before running `gatsby develop` has solved the problem.